# Using regex in Swift to find a substring of a string

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I'm using the following code to find a substring using regex in Swift:

```
    let searchString = "Please contact us at <a href=\"tel:8882223434\" ><font color=\"#003871\"><b> 888.222.3434 </b></font></a> for assistance"
    let regexp = "^\\d+(\\.\\d+)*$"
    if let range = searchString.range(of:regexp, options: .regularExpression) {
        let result = searchString.substring(with:range)
        print(result) // <---- not printing the resulting string
    }
```

The desired output is `888.222.3434`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the anchors and replace `*` with `+`.

```
let regexp = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)+"
```

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(\\.\\d+)+` - one or more sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked out perfectly for my need!